# Save the state of a variable in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a user checklist, where I want to save his progess everytime he checks and closes/opens the application.

Here is what i have done so far:

**HTML**

```
      <i class="white-circle" ng-class="{'green-circle': isToggled1 === true}" ng-click="isToggled1 = !isToggled1">1</i>
      <i class="white-circle" ng-class="{'green-circle': isToggled2 === true}" ng-click="isToggled2 = !isToggled2">2</i>
      <i class="white-circle" ng-class="{'green-circle': isToggled3 === true}" ng-click="isToggled3 = !isToggled3">3</i>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('starter.rencontreController', ['ngSanitize', 

'LocalStorageModule'])
.directive('toggleClass', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        element.toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
      });
    }
  }

})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

    .state('rencontre', {
      url: '/rencontre',
      templateUrl: 'templates/rencontre.html',
      controller: 'rencontreController'
    });
})

.config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
  localStorageServiceProvider
    .setStorageType('sessionStorage');
})

.controller('rencontreController', function ($scope, localStorageService){

    $scope.isToggled1 = localStorageService.get('isToggled1') ? localStorageService.get('isToggled1') : false;


  scope.$watch('isToggled1', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      localStorageService.set('isToggled1', newValue);
  });
```

The problem is I do not know how to store "isToggled" variables.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you do `$scope.isToggled1` and `$scope.isToggled2`?

Answer (score 1):

One of the options, you could use browser [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for that, on angular you have this plugin: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

After configuring on app startup phase

```
myApp.config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
  localStorageServiceProvider
    .setPrefix('myApp')
    .setStorageType('sessionStorage')
    .setNotify(true, true)
});
```

you can do like so in your controller:

```
//when user checks the box
localStorageService.set(MY_CHECKBOX_NAME, true);
```

**UPD**

You need an object in your controller (in your case it's an `array` since you have **list** of similar things) that will keep the state of each of them (it also can have other properties, like `title` for example).

```
//in controller
 $scope.items = [{
  state: false,
  title:'item1'
 },
{
  state: false,
  title:'item2'
},
{
  state: false,
  title:'item3'
 }];

//in template
<i ng-repeat="i in items" class="white-circle" ng-class="{'green-circle': i.state === true}" ng-click="i.state = !i.state">{{$index}} {{i.title}}</i>
```

Comment: Yes, use localStorage for saving your progress is the best solution. Unless you need to upload the progress to a database, but I doubt this is the case.

Comment: I know but My_Checkbox_Name will be what? White-circle?

Answer (score -1):

Your localStorage value are not updated by changes. If you want it to work, you need to make a function to store the value in the localStorage, either using ng-click or using a save button to trigger this function.
It's also cleaner to change the values in controller instead of in view.

Upon initiating your controller, you check if the field in your localStorage exists. If there is value, then assign this value to the value to retrieve your stored values from last time. If there is no value, then initialize default values.

Here is how I would do it :

In your controller:

```
.controller('rencontreController', function ($scope, localStorageService){

var defaultValues = [
    {index: 1, isToggled: false},
    {index: 2, isToggled: false},
    {index: 3, isToggled: false}
];
var storedObj = localStorageService.get("storedObj");
if (storedObj = undefined) {
    $scope.obj = defaultValues;
else {
    $scope.obj = storedObj;
}

//add a function to store the value
$scope.toggle = function(index) {
    // code to change the value of the clicked index

    localStorageService.set("storedObj", $scope.obj);
}
```

In your html :

```
<i class="white-circle" ng-class="{'green-circle': item.isToggled}" ng-click="$scope.toggle(item.index)" ng-repeat="item in $scope.obj">{{item.index}}</i>
```

UPDATED:

added `var storedObj`

```
var storedObj = localStorageService.get("storedObj");
if (storedObj = undefined) {
    $scope.obj = defaultValues;
else {
    $scope.obj = storedObj;
}
```

Comment: I  have this error ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. I have updated my answer.

Comment: When i use ngrepeat all  my circles disappear So i  modified your answer to this: <i class="whitecircle" ng-class="{'green-circle': isToggled1 === true}" ng-click="$scope.toggle(isToggled1)">1</i>  var defaultValues = [
    { isToggled1: false},
    { isToggled2: false},
    { isToggled3: false}
];
var savedObj= localStorageService.get("storedObj");
if ( savedObj = 'undefined') {
    $scope.obj = defaultValues;
  }
else {
    $scope.obj = savedObj;
}

$scope.toggle = function(isToggled1) {

    localStorageService.set("storedObj", $scope.obj);
}  but its not working

Comment: Your template syntax is wrong. And ** if (myvar != undefined ) { ** is also nonconventional